# Is there a way to make a flat surface, that is perpendicular to the camera, visible in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-3

As seen [in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSGK0.png) we have a rectangle which is 2 Dimensional in a 3D space.
When I rotate said rectangle ([Slightly rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2GLO.png)) so that the normal of this plate is perpendicular to the camera, it vanishes ([Heavily rotated Rectangle just before vanishing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWHRc.png)). The intuition would tell me, that the plate is supposed to show a single line of pixels, however this is not the case (but certainly what I'm trying to achieve). This Problem seems so trivial, but I can't find a solution to it.

Comment: You could draw the outlines of the square separately (with a draw call of GL_LINES) which would still be visible when viewed at that angle, or you could draw a cuboid that has a small thickness instead of a 2D square.

Comment: (answer to a deleted comment) Then, I don't see an elegant solution. When you project a 3D triangle onto an orthogonal plane (which is what your camera transformation does in this case), the resulting 2D triangle is degenerate and has not area that could be rendered.
The outline solution should work for more complex models, though. You could draw all models twice (once with polygonMode GL_LINES, then with GL_FILL).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I deleted my previous comment because I didn't test it before replying. I tried it now and it works almost as intended. The lines are visible. When I use a more complex model it somehow draws lines that shouldn't be there (i assume my model is at fault, but I can't tell). When rendering  both, GL_LINES seems to also show the lines between the vertices, when the camera is not looking perpendicular. This way you see the outlines of every polygon.

Comment: I sadly can't share the real model because this project is work related. Else I could outline the problem more deeply.

Comment: As long as the lines are shaded equally to the filled areas, they shoud be invisible on the model, but I may be wrong. Maybe I am misunderstanding "When rendering both, GL_LINES seems to also show the lines between the vertices, when the camera is not looking perpendicular". Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Hendrik you do realize that lines have different indexing than triangles do ? If not that'd explain what you describe for the more complex model.

Comment: @LJᛃ Doesn't that only apply to calling glDrawArrays (or similar) with one of the GL_LINE* modes? I thought glPolygonMode wouldn't change anything about the drawing mode or indexing order.

Comment: @eike I think you're correct, I missed that you were recommending using `glPolygonMode` :)

Comment: @eike I think the solution you suggested is the only one that really works. My Model seems to be incorrect because quite a few lines are drawn where there shouldn't be any. I could initially see all the lines because I activated GL_CULL_FACE and looked at the opposite direction of the normal. It works fine now. Thanks!